# No KeyEvent is hitting in ListView Item Edit in C# Win-Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, event-handling, keyboard-events

I am working on a Win-Forms application , Having a listview with some items displayed , Need to edit the labels of the item .
So Enabled `LabelEdit` property to true, and invoking

```
listView1.SelectedItems[0].BeginEdit();
```

on a context menu item click. It's working fine.

Now i need to validate the characters inputted by the user in item name, 
like not allowing special characters in the name , So registered `keyDown event` in the list view , But that is not getting hit in label edit mode , I tried all other key events , but none is getting hit .

One solution is to do the validation in

```
private void listView1_AfterLabelEdit(object sender, LabelEditEventArgs e)
{
    // Validation code goes here
}
```

But i don't want to do this , i want to show a tool tip if user enters a invalid character

Can someone tell which event to use ??
Any help would be appretated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListView dynamically creates a TextBox control when the user starts editing the label.  This control is not wrapped by Winforms and does not interact with its parent's events beyond the OnBefore/AfterLabelEdit events.

That can be fixed.  The LVM_GETEDITCONTROL message allows you to obtain a handle to that textbox.  The NativeWindow class can then subclass the control so you can intercept its messages.  Like the keyboard message you are interested in.

Here's an example, it adds the LabelKeyPress event to ListView.  You can write an event handler for it and set the e.Handled property to true to prevent the key press from being used.  Add a new class to your project and paste the code below.  Compile.  Drop the new control from the top of the toolbox, replacing the original ListView.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class ListViewEx : ListView {
    public event KeyEventHandler LabelKeyDown = delegate { };
    public event KeyEventHandler LabelKeyUp = delegate { };
    public event KeyPressEventHandler LabelKeyPress = delegate { };
    private LabelTextBox Label;

    public ListViewEx() {
        Label = new LabelTextBox(this);
    }
    protected void OnLabelKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e) { LabelKeyDown(this, e); }
    protected void OnLabelKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e) { LabelKeyUp(this, e); }
    protected void OnLabelKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e) { LabelKeyPress(this, e); }

    protected override void OnBeforeLabelEdit(LabelEditEventArgs e) {
        const int LVM_GETEDITCONTROL = 0x1000 + 24;
        var hdl = SendMessage(this.Handle, LVM_GETEDITCONTROL, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        Label.AssignHandle(hdl);
        base.OnBeforeLabelEdit(e);
    }
    protected override void OnAfterLabelEdit(LabelEditEventArgs e) {
        Label.ReleaseHandle();
        base.OnAfterLabelEdit(e);
    }

    private class LabelTextBox : NativeWindow {
        private ListViewEx Parent;
        public LabelTextBox(ListViewEx parent) { this.Parent = parent; }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
            switch (m.Msg) {
                case 0x100:
                    var args = new KeyEventArgs((Keys)m.WParam.ToInt32());
                    Parent.OnLabelKeyDown(args);
                    if (args.Handled) return;
                    break;
                case 0x101:
                    var args2 = new KeyEventArgs((Keys)m.WParam.ToInt32());
                    Parent.OnLabelKeyUp(args2);
                    break;
                case 0x102:
                    var args3 = new KeyPressEventArgs((char)m.WParam.ToInt32());
                    Parent.OnLabelKeyPress(args3);
                    if (args3.Handled) return;
                    break;
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with Form.KeyPreview ?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview(v=vs.100).aspx

you could set up a bool variable to know that you are editing the label, and while it is true, you keep performing validation on the Form.Keydown